# Can you write a selectorlist to one column in SQL?

Tags: python, string, list, selenium, join

first off, I'm not an IT professional/student, I'm only just getting into programming and data so I'm sorry in advance if you think the question isn't formulated well.

I'm doing a hobby project getting to know python and datascraping with selenium. I'm trying to scrape my linkedin page to first fill a relational database and later fill my cv with the data. I'm having problems with writing the data to my database. When I use extract_first() or get(), the data writes to the database just fine. But when I use extract() or getall(), I get the error message that 'operand should contain 1 column(s)'. Which I think means the selectorlist that's the output, is written to the database as different rows in stead of being written to the same row in the database? But I'd like the full selectorlist to be written to the same column and row.

I tried converting the selectorlist to a string (see code below) but this gives me the same output as the selectorlist.

```
jobs= sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').getall()
jobs= [str(jobs[0]), str(''.join(jobs[1:]))]
```

Gives the same output as

```
jobs= sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').getall()
```

Output

```
['job1', 'job2']
```

I'd like the output to come out as a string:

```
['job1, job2']
```

So I can write it to the database into one column (jobs). So column ID has value 1 (for person 1) and column jobs has value 'job1, job2' for ID 1.

Is this possible? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you would *like the output to come out as a* `string` you can pass the *output* (which is a *List*) to a method for conversion as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  def convert_list_to_string(jobs):
      new = ""
      for item in jobs:
      new += item
      return new 

  def main():    
      jobs = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').getall()
      print(convert_list_to_string(jobs)) 

  main()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  job1job2
  ```

If you want to presearve the **`,`** characters then you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  jobs = sel.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]/text()').getall()
  print(','.join(jobs))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  job1,job2
  ```

Comment: I did! Up until this morning I didn't have enough reputation for it to show. Thanks for the answer, works perfectly! Went for the second option but the first option really helped with my understanding of the problem.

Comment: Well, the phrase _getting into programming_ compelled me to construct the answer in the most simplest way. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: Great! I felt a bit worried to ask the question because another question of mine got a couple of downvotes without the voters answering my question so I'm not really sure about my questions. But your answer helped tons!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code.Hope this will work.It will Extract the value into list and then join list items.

```
jobs=[job.text for job in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@class, "t-16 t-black t-bold")]')]
finaltext=','.join(jobs)
```